# Cannot connect to docker daemon

Tags: docker

I have tried everything: add user, tried it with sudo but i didnt fix it.

I tried it as a : sudo docker ps and docker ps

Docker version : 1.11.2
OS/Archlinux

gives an error : Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is the docker daemon running on this host?

```
systemctl status docker :
 ● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.service;  enabled;   vendor preset: disabled)
Active: active (running) since Tue 2016-08-16 12:34:14 UTC; 13min ago
 Docs: https://docs.docker.com
Main PID: 2323 (docker)
Tasks: 21 (limit: 4915)
Memory: 24.2M
  CPU: 649ms
CGroup: /system.slice/docker.service
       ├─2323 /usr/bin/docker daemon -H fd://
       └─2339 docker-containerd -l /var/run/docker/libcontainerd /docker-containerd.sock --runtime docker-run
Aug 16 12:34:13 localhost docker[2323]: time="2016-08-16T12:34:13.730808484Z" level=info msg="[graphdriver] usin
Aug 16 12:34:13 localhost docker[2323]: time="2016-08-16T12:34:13.762838102Z" level=info msg="Graph migration to
Aug 16 12:34:13 localhost docker[2323]: time="2016-08-16T12:34:13.769883452Z" level=info msg="Firewalld running:
Aug 16 12:34:14 localhost docker[2323]: time="2016-08-16T12:34:14.023823826Z" level=info msg="Default bridge (do
Aug 16 12:34:14 localhost docker[2323]: time="2016-08-16T12:34:14.179897054Z" level=info msg="Loading containers
Aug 16 12:34:14 localhost docker[2323]: time="2016-08-16T12:34:14.179994020Z" level=info msg="Loading containers
Aug 16 12:34:14 localhost docker[2323]: time="2016-08-16T12:34:14.180008132Z" level=info msg="Daemon has complet
Aug 16 12:34:14 localhost docker[2323]: time="2016-08-16T12:34:14.180026066Z" level=info msg="Docker daemon" com
Aug 16 12:34:14 localhost docker[2323]: time="2016-08-16T12:34:14.187118716Z" level=info msg="API listen on 0.0.
Aug 16 12:34:14 localhost systemd[1]: Started Docker Application Container Engine.


ps aux | grep docker
root      2681  0.1  0.9 553580 35416 ?        Ssl  12:59   0:00 /usr/bin/docker daemon -H fd://
root      2694  0.0  0.3 287016 11724 ?        Ssl  12:59   0:00 docker-containerd -l /var/run/docker/libcontainerd/docker-containerd.sock --runtime docker-runc --start-timeout 2m
cuneyt    2835  0.0  0.0  11056  2228 pts/1    S+   13:01   0:00 grep docker
```

**EDIT** : When i run manualy docker daemon is working and API listen on /var/run/docker.sock

When i start it with systemctl start docker API Listen on 0.0.0.0:3000 i think that is the problem but i dont know how to fix it any idea ?

```
systemctl cat docker.service

[Service]
Type=notify
# the default is not to use systemd for cgroups because the delegate issues still
# exists and systemd currently does not support the cgroup feature set required
# for containers run by docker
ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker daemon -H fd://
MountFlags=slave
LimitNOFILE=1048576
LimitNPROC=1048576
LimitCORE=infinity
TimeoutStartSec=0
# set delegate yes so that systemd does not reset the cgroups of docker containers
Delegate=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: Did you well followed the installation process ? https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Docker

Comment: yes :/ it's working on our other computer

Comment: Please paste the output of `systemctl cat docker.service`

Comment: @Boynux add the logs ty

Comment: i didnt fix it and reinstall the OS so if anyone cant fix it, reinstallation is good idea :)

Comment: You can find answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44847690/8073649). It might be helpful for you.

Answer (score 2):

The installation [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/ubuntulinux/#/create-a-docker-group) states:

> The docker daemon binds to a Unix socket instead of a TCP port. By
>   default that Unix socket is owned by the user root and other users can
>   access it with sudo. For this reason, docker daemon always runs as the
>   root user.
>
> So, To avoid having to use sudo when you use the docker command,
>   create a Unix group called docker and add users to it. When the docker
>   daemon starts, it makes the ownership of the Unix socket read/writable
>   by the docker group.

To create the docker group and add your user:

Login as a user with sudo privileges. (the one you used to install docker)
Create the docker group.

```
$ sudo groupadd docker
```

Add your user to docker group.

```
$ sudo usermod -aG docker $USER
```

Log out and log back in.
This ensures your user is running with the correct permissions.
Verify your work by running docker without sudo.

```
$ docker run hello-world
```

If you're still getting the same error, check if the DOCKER_HOST environment variable is not set for your shell. If it is, unset it.

```
$ unset DOCKER_HOST
```

Hope this helps