# Cannot connect to the Docker daemon

Tags: ubuntu, docker, ubuntu-12.04

I started up a ubuntu virtual machine using vagrant. The version of Ubuntu running is 12.04 precise. I installed docker using the package method outlined on the docker website: Docker version 1.13.0, build 49bf474.

I added docker to upstart, and am able to start and stop docker through the upstart commands:

```
$ sudo service docker stop
docker stop/waiting

$ sudo service docker start
docker start/running, process 22994
```

I then try running the command:

```
$ sudo docker run hello-world
docker: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

I've looked through the numerous articles on stack overflow, but most of them deal with user permissions. At this point, I wouldn't mind having to put in 'sudo' if I can just get it to run.

[Cannot connect to docker daemon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38971668/cannot-connect-to-docker-daemon) pointed me to an attempt to unset the 'DOCKER_HOST' value. I attemtped this with no luck. I tried the 5th answer from [Docker command can't connect to Docker daemon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33562109/docker-command-cant-connect-to-docker-daemon), where it's mentioned that this is a network issue, but again with no luck. I tried the 6th answer with adding the docker key, again with no luck.

Does anyone have any ideas of where else I can look as to why I'm getting this error?

EDIT:

When I run $ sudo service docker stauts, I get docker start/running, process {pId}. What's strange is that every time I run it, pId is different.

```
~$ sudo service docker status
docker start/running, process 28630
~$ sudo service docker status
docker start/running, process 28881
~$ sudo service docker status
docker start/running, process 29007
```

EDIT 2:

I found [Docker can't connect to docker daemon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21871479/docker-cant-connect-to-docker-daemon?rq=1) where one answer recommended running debug mode. Unfortunately, running

```
sudo docker --debug
```

Kept throwing the standard 'help' error where it did not recognize the flag. I also tried '-d' (per the answer) and '-D' (per the help file) with the same response.

Just looking into things, I tried ps.

```
$ ps aux | grep docker
root     18776  0.0  3.5  87904 13328 ?        Ssl  20:51   0:00 /usr/bin/dockerd --raw-logs
```

root     18785  0.0  1.2  59860  4808 ?        Ssl  20:51   0:00 docker-containerd -l unix:///var/run/docker/libcontainerd/docker-containerd.sock --metrics-interval=0 --start-timeout 2m --state-dir /var/run/docker/libcontainerd/containerd --shim docker-containerd-shim --runtime docker-runc
vagrant  18792  0.0  0.2  11676   948 pts/0    R+   20:51   0:00 grep --color=auto docker

but has the odd behaviour that everytime I run it, the pId changes.

Comment: What does `sudo dockerd` print?

Comment: $ sudo dockerd
INFO[0000] libcontainerd: new containerd process, pid: 9942
WARN[0000] containerd: low RLIMIT_NOFILE changing to max  current=1024 max=4096
FATA[0001] Your Linux kernel version 3.2.0-23-generic is not supported for running docker. Please upgrade your kernel to 3.10.0 or newer.

Answer (score 2):

I feel silly adding an answer. I think I found the issue. When I looked in the logs for docker

```
$ sudo tail -f /var/log/upstart/docker.log -n 500
```

I saw the same message repeating every second:

```
time="2017-01-28T20:56:15.265328447Z" level=info msg="libcontainerd: new containerd process, pid: 29392"
time="2017-01-28T20:56:16.271350352Z" level=fatal msg="Your Linux kernel version 3.2.0-23-generic is not supported for running docker. Please upgrade your kernel to 3.10.0 or newer."
/var/run/docker.sock is up
```

I haven't attemtped it yet, but I think the issue is with the version of UBUNTU I'm using. I'm going to try moving to a newer version and see if that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the tips! In my case I'm seeing `[graphdriver] prior storage driver aufs failed: driver not supported`.