# Run docker build in ubuntu:16.04 docker

Tags: ubuntu, docker

I want to build a docker image in docker container.

So, I tried to create a docker-installed ubuntu docker image following https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/ubuntu/, but failed.

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

RUN apt-get update && \ 
    apt-get install -y \
        apt-transport-https \
        ca-certificates \
        software-properties-common

RUN curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | apt-key add -

RUN apt-key fingerprint 0EBFCD88

RUN add-apt-repository \
   "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu \
   $(lsb_release -cs) \
   stable"

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y docker-ce
```

When I run `docker images` or other commands on the docker image created by above Dockerfile, the error happens.

```
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
```

Is there any way to solve this problem? Thanks.

Comment: The thing is called Docker-in-Docker (dind) and is very tricky. Please explain what you are **really** trying to do.

Comment: @TatsuyukiIshi I want to use this docker image to build server, that builds and create a docker images to deploy.
Following this document http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ko_kr/codebuild/latest/userguide/sample-docker.html, it looks possible because they build docker in docker.

Comment: What CI solution are you using? Running Docker inside Docker is possible but strongly discouraged due to it's tricky nature.

Comment: @TatsuyukiIshi I'm using AWS CodeBuild

Comment: Here's a link to [top Google result](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/sample-docker.html)

Comment: @TatsuyukiIshi I saw that but I failed to do that on my docker image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides the affect of AWS environment, the problem you have is caused by that you did not start docker daemon inside your container, as the error message shown.

Here's the steps to show how to make it work manually:

1. Start and enter a container using the image built from your `Dockerfile`:

   `docker run --privileged -it dind /bin/bash`

And here is the problem you have:

```
root@82d6eab69331:/# docker images
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
```

2. Start `docker daemon` inside this container:

   `root@82d6eab69331:~# /usr/bin/dockerd -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock > dockerd.log 2>&1 &`
3. Check log file to make sure it started correctly, and then try `docker images`:

   `root@82d6eab69331:~# docker images
    REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE`

So you may need to add `entrypoint` to start `docker daemon` in your `Dockerfile`. I test on environment of `CentOS 7.2` and `docker 1.12`. Hope this could be helpful to you :-)

Comment: Glad to help :)

Comment: Thanks for the `dockerd` startup command which really helped my a lot using `ubuntu:bionic` as the base image for Docker-in-Docker installations. For me the last building block (having `--priviledged` and the mentioned startup command in place), was to switch the storage driver (as described *Start a daemon instance* in https://hub.docker.com/_/docker/) to `vfs`. To switch to `vfs` you need to create a `/etc/docker/daemon.json` with `{ "storage-driver": "vfs" }` [according to the docs](https://docs.docker.com/storage/storagedriver/vfs-driver/#configure-docker-with-the-vfs-storage-driver).

Answer (score 0):

AWS CodeBuild doesn't "[..] allow customers to bring in their own Docker-in-Docker images [..]" yet.

> We currently only support Docker-in-Docker (dind) with the official CodeBuild images

[Source](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=761184&#761184) (Jan 12, 2017):

Answer (score 0):

cannot connect to Docker daemon - you might need to run...
Maybe, you can see the result this command.

```
$ sudo docker images
```

You should add your user in docker group.
And then, you can use docker command without 'sudo'.

```
$ sudo usermod -aG docker ${USER}
$ sudo service docker restart
```

**Next, you have to logout in your OS**.
Finally, when you login, you can use docker command without 'sudo'.